# How do you get subject & title from a Word document (without opening it)?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I would like to read the title and subject fields from a Word document, but would rather not have the overhead of firing up Word to do it.

If, in Windows Explorer, I display the title and subject columns, and then navigate to a folder that has Word documents in it, then this information is displayed. What mechanism is being used to do this *(aside from Shell extensions)* because its fast *(but I don't know if you actually need Word installed for this to work)*, so I'm guessing its not firing up Word and opening each document.

I've found a link to Dsofile.dll, which I presume I could use, but does this work for .doc and .docx files and is it the only way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well... as one might assume that the time of the ".doc" file is passing, here is one way to get the subject and title from a ".docx" file *(or ".xlsx" file for that matter)*.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging; // Assembly WindowsBase.dll

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        String file = Path.Combine(path, "Doc1.docx");

        Package docx = Package.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        String subject = docx.PackageProperties.Subject;
        String title = docx.PackageProperties.Title;
        docx.Close();
     }
  }
}
```

I hope this is useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can read it via XML, too: [How to extract information from Office files by using Office file formats and schemas](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/840817)

Here is [another example](http://omegacoder.com/?p=555) on how to read a Word doc programmatically.

One way or the other you'll have to look inside the file at some point!

Comment: Thanks Josh, but one of those links is a method which fires up Word (via OLE automation) and gets the properties, and the other will only work for Open XML documents. Opening the file is fine, but using something as big and heavy as Word seems like overkill. I was doubting that the Shell extensions do it that way.

Comment: Well since the document types are so different you will either have to use two solutions or the one solution - automation. Perhaps you can inspect the file manually to determine how to extract the info another way but I think that may not be easy.